# cannot connect to jupyter notebook sever kernel

Tags: server, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I was unable to execute my code in jupyter. It stuck in connecting to the kernel.

SSH works fine; I can edit my code in the browser; I just can't execute it.

I searched in StackOverflow, they say it is something wrong about WebSocket or proxy, But I didn't run any proxies by now. I also tried different ports, different browser. It is still the same.

In the terminal, It shows that

```
[I 12:16:33.817 NotebookApp] Kernel started: de4e320d-260f-4b02-8823-6a23af662840
[I 12:16:36.436 NotebookApp] Adapting to protocol v5.1 for kernel de4e320d-260f-4b02-8823-6a23af662840
/home/pi/.virtualenvs/raceon/lib/python3.5/site-packages/notebook/base/zmqhandlers.py:284: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'get' was never awaited
  super(AuthenticatedZMQStreamHandler, self).get(*args, **kwargs)
[W 12:16:37.591 NotebookApp] Replacing stale connection: de4e320d-260f-4b02-8823-6a23af662840:66db65124be8468dac
```

Answer (score 0):

There appears to have been a recent update to tornado that causes this.

We worked around this by pinning tornado to 5.1.1 in the jupyter environment (or if you're feeling brave, "pip uninstall tornado" followed by "pip install tornado==5.1.1")